# Opposite of "I got this"

Tags: idioms

I've got this as in a response to "Can you handle it?". What's the opposite of "I got this"? "I don't got it" sounds weird and wrong.

Comment: In that sense, "I got it" is a colloquial idiom which is fixed. It never changes. It doesn't have a literal meaning, and there's no way to negate it using grammatical constructs.  It just means "Yes, I can handle it" or "Yes, I can do it".  So, the opposite would be "No, I can't".

Comment: "I don't got it" is the colloquial opposite, though it's kind of purposefully ungrammatical. See it, for example, here: https://youtu.be/TfIJ5_gI054?t=201

Answer (score 1):

If the query is about learning something "I'm drawing a blank" might be used. But if the question is about an ability to perform some task (particularly regarding available time) then a simple "no" would be sufficient. "I'm booked" if it's desirable to give at least some explanation for why.

Comment: Other responses for different reasons: "I'm tapped out" (I don't have the time, energy, or money); "I can't deal" (I'm not able to accommodate the situation); "You're on your own" (I can't or won't help).